# Is there notation to indicate that a variable in an equation is very large or very small?

Tags: notation

I'm looking for a typographical shorthand for writing it out separately. Is there a recommended suffix or a dot or something?

Comment: They use $x>>0$ to say "for $x$ sufficiently large".

Comment: You might be interested in [Landau symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Follow-up to the above comment: Look up "Little-o notation".

Answer (score 2):

Use 
$$
x\gg a
$$ 
to say that the variable $x$ is sufficiently larger than $a$ and use 
$$
x \ll a 
$$
to say that the variable $x$ is sufficiently less than $a$.

Comment: Yes, but say it in words once, because $\ll$ can mean something else.